# Applying majority of page CSS to a jQuery FadeOut?

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net

I have this Jquery fadeout code:

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function () {
    $(".loader").fadeOut("fast");
})
</script>
```

And the CSS for .loader is

```
.loader {
position: fixed;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 9999;
background-color: #000000;  
}
```

So when the page loads, the user is seeing a completely black screen (background-color element) and all other page elements effectively fadeIn from the black screen.

All pages are using the MasterPage/CSS layout - I'd like instead of just applying the background color to .loader, apply all of the elements so when a postback occurs, the borders, margins, images and menus etc look like they are frozen, just the new elements like the new controls and text which change between pages effectively fadeIn.

What's the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

So you want some parts off your page to fade in, not whole page. You can do this if you change in css file width,height,left,top tributes. Next you can create new entry in css file something like loader2. Here is something to experiment, you can add more loader class if needed.

css file:

```
.loader {
position: fixed;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
width: 300px;
height: 100px;
z-index: 9999;
background-color: #000000;  
}

.loader2 {
position: fixed;
left: 350px;
top: 150px;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
z-index: 9999;
background-color: #000000;  
}
```

and change Jquery to:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function () {
    $(".loader").fadeOut("fast");
    $(".loader2").fadeOut("fast");
})
```